# r merge model.matrix with the dataset

Tags: r, merge, model.matrix

I have a dataset like this.

```
library(lme4)
data("sleepstudy")    
head(sleepstudy)
```

First I create a matrix of X values.

```
 X <- cbind(1, sleepstudy$Days)
```

Then I create a matrix Z

```
 Z <- model.matrix(~ 0 + Subject + Subject:Days, data = sleepstudy)
```

How do I attach the model.matrix Z with matrix Z , such that the two matrices or dataframes are merged in the right manner.

Thanks.

Comment: `head(cbind(sleepstudy, cbind(X, Z)))`?

Comment: @TarJae, appears right to me. Thanks.